# Custom fonts in Getuikit with less preprocessor

Tags: css, fonts, uikit, less

What is right way to make available custom fonts (e.g. google fonts) in my new theme? 
It look like this issue: 
https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/111

I did make what they says, only paste this code in the uikit.less:

```
 /* Custom Fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensanscondensed';
    src: url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700);
}
```

But it did not works. And i cant find where i should specify **font-family**  for some elements(nav, top-menu, etc .. )

I would be grateful for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url that you are pasting in the `src` property is an url of a css file (that google generates for you to import the font faces). You can see that it already generates font faces for you:

[http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans%20Condensed:300,300italic,700)

What you need to do in your style sheet file is just importing the css from the url. Something like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700)
```

and then you can use it like so:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
```

#### [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbFLE)

Comment: OK, your example is for CSS, but how I can import with less into getuikit framework?

Comment: **Same code should work for LESS!** And in uikit you could just use google fonts in your [**customizer.json**](http://www.getuikit.com/docs/documentation_customizer-json.html). Something like this might work: `"Google Fonts": [{"name": "Open Sans Condensed", "value": "'Open Sans Condensed'","url":"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans%20Condensed:300,300italic,700"}]`